# OpenCV subdivision-consistent Rect2f to Rect2i rounding

Tags: c++, opencv

In OpenCV, when making cv::Rect2i from cv::Rect2f, the library just rounds each component of cv::Rect2f, i.e. x, y, width, height. This causes holes and overlays when converting a set of subdivision rects, for example, intervals 0.4..1.6 and 1.6..3.2 would be rounded to 0..1 and 2..4, while the desired integer subdivision would be 0..2 and 2..3, i.e. each subinterval includes those integer pixels, whose centers lie withing the corresponding floating point interval.

Now I use the following "bicycle" function to solve the problem:

```
cv::Rect2i integer_rect(const cv::Rect2f & rect)
{
    int x1 = std::floor(rect.x + 0.5f);
    int y1 = std::floor(rect.y + 0.5f);
    int x2 = std::floor(rect.x + rect.width + 0.5f);
    int y2 = std::floor(rect.y + rect.height + 0.5f);
    return cv::Rect2i(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
}
```

Does the OpenCV already contain such a conversion function which I could mislook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like `rect3`.

```
cv::Rect2f rect1(0.4, 1.4, 1.6, 3.2);
cv::Rect2i rect2 = rect1;
cv::Rect2i rect3(rect1.tl(), rect1.br()); // tl for top-left and br for bottom-right

cout << rect1 << endl;
cout << rect2 << endl;
cout << rect3 << endl;
```

outputs

```
[1.6 x 3.2 from (0.4, 1.4)]
[2 x 3 from (0, 1)]
[2 x 4 from (0, 1)]
```